# In VBScript, is there a way to tell if IE is busy loading something (e.g. a page or XHR)?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, vbscript, internet-explorer-7, hta

I am writing an HTML Application (HTA) that runs fullscreen and allows users to browse a list of selected websites. I notice that sometimes when you click on link to load an external website, there is no feedback to the user that the browser has accepted the request and has started trying to load the page.

In Internet explorer, you get a little rotating favicon in the active tab and a progress bar in the notification area to indicate that the browser is loading something. I would like to include this functionality in my HTA.

**Things I have tried:**

The list of websites appears in a menu at the top of the screen and the website the user is browsing appears in an iframe below that. I've tried using Internet Explorer's `onreadystatechange` event to detect when the iframe's location changes, but I've noticed that the readyState doesn't change to `"loading"` as soon as the link is clicked - it seems to fire only after it receives a response back from the server. So if the server takes 5 seconds to respond with something, then the HTA appears to be sitting there doing nothing for 5 seconds.

Any ideas? Thanks for taking the time to read this and respond =)

Kind regards

-Iain

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `ReadyState` rather than 'Busy'

```
do until ie.readyState = 4 : wscript.sleep 10 : loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
While oIE.Busy
   WScript.Sleep 100
Wend
```